# Is there any way post in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

I want to handle POST method in selenium. ( To login fast as requests )
I've succeed login in requests.post

in requests:

```
session = requests.session()
session.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

However, it seems that selenium doesn't have any method like POST in requests.
So, I want to save the session, and applyy in selenium.

Just like this:

```
post and login in session -> selenium.get() Which url that only users can get in
```

How can I?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is built to simulate user GUI actions like clicking on elements, reading their texts, scrolling the page etc.
Performing API POST, GET etc. requests are **not** supported by Selenium.
There are several dedicated tools for such actions like *Postman* and SW libraries allowing you to perform such actions programmatically.